# Нужно ли ставить запятую: "Спросить у эксперта как дела"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую: "Спросить у эксперта как дела" по правилам?

Answer (score 3):

*Надо спросить у эксперта, **как (у него) дела**.*

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным **изъяснительным**.  Запятая ставится перед союзным словом ***КАК***.

Главное предложение односоставное **безличное:** предикатив ***надо*** с модальным значением (можно, нельзя, нужно, надо, необходимо).